# How do I specify DLNA PlaySingle support in my Media Server Device Profile?

Tags: dlna

DLNA CTT 1.5.00.51 Test 7.3.80.1,2,3,4 MM CDS DLNA PlaySingle URI Value is failing with the error message "Not Applicable: The device profile reports the DUT does not support PlaySingle URIs"

I have changed my connection manager to return

```
"http-get:*:audio/mpeg:*"
",http-get:*:audio/wav:*"
",dlna-playsingle:*:audio/mpeg:*"
",dlna-playsingle:*:audio/wav:*"
```

when GetProtocolInfo is invoked.

Is that the right string? Or am I way of track?

I also tried

```
"http-get:*:audio/mpeg:*"
",http-get:*:audio/wav:*"
",playsingle-http-get:*:audio/mpeg:*"
",playsingle-http-get:*:audio/wav:*"
```

I have read the DLNA and searched the web but there didn't seem to be much documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed a test tool configuration option.

In the CTT create a new device profile; on the option page select "Play Modes" then check the "Play Single URI's" option.

Thereafter 7.3.80.1,2,3,4 and the other 7.3.80.* test cases will be available.

There is no need to alter the devices profile or the results of GetProtocolInfo.

(Maybe it should read "PlaySingle URIs")